# Spring-Integration DSL transform() method using name of a bean as the transformer

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl

When creating an `IntegrationFlow` that uses `from()` or `channel()` or `gateway()`, I can refer to a channel by simply giving the `String` name of the channel. However, with a `transform()` operation using transformers that are beans, I  have to include those `Autowired` beans in the constructor.  This can be fastidious when then are a large number of transformations in the flow.

Is there a simple way of referring to a `Bean` used by a `transform()` without autowiring the bean in the constructor?

```
@Component
public class DoubleIntegerValueTransformer implements GenericTransformer<Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer transform(Integer source) {
        return source * 2;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class AutowiredTransformerFlows {

    // Would like to eliminate the constructor and local instance variable
    private final DoubleIntegerValueTransformer doubleIntegerValueTransformer;

    public AutowiredTransformerFlows(DoubleIntegerValueTransformer doubleIntegerValueTransformer) {
        this.doubleIntegerValueTransformer = doubleIntegerValueTransformer;
    }

    @Bean(name = "autowiredTransformerFlow")
    IntegrationFlow usesBeanAsTransformer() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("autowiredTransformChannel")
                .filter("(payload % 2) == 1", discardReturnsCurrentMessage())
                .transform(doubleIntegerValueTransformer)
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a parameter to the bean factory method:

```java
@Bean(name = "autowiredTransformerFlow")
IntegrationFlow usesBeanAsTransformer(DoubleIntegerValueTransformer doubleIntegerValueTransformer) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("autowiredTransformChannel")
            .filter("(payload % 2) == 1", discardReturnsCurrentMessage())
            .transform(doubleIntegerValueTransformer)
            .get();
}
```

The bean should be in a `@Configuration` class, not a `@Component` class.

Comment: Seems to work even with ```Component```, at least for a bean defined in a separate file.  Thanks very much!